# Power calculation for a one-stage, single arm trial with continuous primary outcome

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, continuous-data, clinical-trials

An early-stage single-arm clinical trial is being planned to evaluate the efficacy and safety of treatment for a bacterial infection.

The primary outcome is binary - proportion with >0.5 log10 reduction in bacterial load - for which power is estimated using the a'Hern exact single-stage phase II design.

If the primary outcome were continuous (ie, log10 change from baseline in bacterial load). What would be the best method to calculate the power/sample size?